# Добавление записей в бд по нажатию кнопки из нескольких TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Если добавлять из 1 текстбокса, работает, в чем ошибка?
Duplicate Inicialization of member "nameAnswer"

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (AppConnect.modelOdb.Answers.Count(x => x.nameAnswer == TxbAnswer1.Text) > 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("error", "error",
                   MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
               return;
           }
           try
           {
              Answers userObj = new Answers()
               {
                  nameAnswer = TxbAnswer1.Text,
                  nameAnswer = TxbAnswer2.Text,
                  nameAnswer = TxbAnswer3.Text,
                  nameAnswer = TxbAnswer4.Text,
              };
               AppConnect.modelOdb.Answers.Add(userObj);
               AppConnect.modelOdb.SaveChanges();
               MessageBox.Show("Данные добавлены", "",
                 MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);


             
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Ошибка добавления данных " + ex.Message, "",
                  MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
           }
```

Comment: `Answers` покажите, а вообще вы пытаетесь присвоить одно поле 4 раза. Что будет, нсли переиенную присвоить 4 раза? Верно, там останется только роследнее значение, вот и у вас то же самое.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю,  поэтому и решил задать вопрос, потому что не понимаю как это правильно можно оформить

Comment: Класс покажите, без него неизвестно что отвечать

Comment: по сути это все что есть, в классе AppConnect  у меня просто строка подключения к бд